# define code section

Tags: linux, assembly, 64-bit, nasm, elf

I'm tring to assemble the following code using Nasm:

```
section .stage1_main 
extern stage1_get_stage2_addr
global stage1_main

stage1_main:
    sub rsp, 0x8
    call stage1_get_stage2_addr 
    cmp rax, -1 
    jz error
    add rsp, 0x8
    push stage1_main
    jmp rax 

error:
     ret
```

.stage1_main is a new section that I defined. the probelm is that Nasm define it as a DATA section

```
objdump -h main.o
```

main.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

Sections:

Idx Name          Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn
  0 .stage1_main  0000001b  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  000001c0  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, READONLY, **DATA**

I need a code section...
is there a way to define my section as a CODE section (like .text)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make your `section` directive state explicitly that the section's contents are executable:

`section .stage1_main exec`

and you might also want to insist on 16-byte alignment (which `nasm` will do automatically for the `.text` section):

`section .stage1_main exec align=16`